# How to render data from multiple tables from MySQL using React, Spring Boot?

Tags: java, mysql, reactjs

I have four tables in a database. When the user uses the Search option from the React application I want the search button to query all the tables and display data from all the tables which is AWS RDS MYSQL. How should I proceed? I am using Spring boot, mysql, and react.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at [JPA Respositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RC1/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.query-methods.query-creation). Since your db seams to be small, a simple repository method like that one should make the trick.

However, if you have a more complicated requirement, you can use a [Spring Projection](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections).  Create a query that retrieves all the fields you'll need, even if they're from different tables, and map the result into a [Spring Projection](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections)

Using spring data jpa you should create a method in your repository that returns a list of your projection class:

```
public interface MyRepository extends Repository<MyEntityProjection, Long> {
   
   @Query("SELECT ... WHERE field = ?1")
   List<MyEntityProjection> getData(String param);
}
```

The projection class should be something like this:

```
public interface MyEntityProjection {
    String getField();
    String getField2();
}
```

Adding as many fields as your query returns.

Read the docs I linked for more information and examples.